# What is an enumerative definition?

Tags: logic, terminology, definitions

W. Kent Wilson in his book argues for developing an enumerative definition of concepts. An enumerative definition formulates its meaning by enumerating the objects or phenomena that fall under the definition of the concept in question. Can you help me understand what he means by this? Wilson writes:

"An enumerative definition of a term gives the extension of the term. Strictly speaking, it must give the complete extension of the definiendum, but often only a partial extension is given. The extension may be given singly, where each object denoted by the definiendum is listed" (p. 13)

Wilson, W. K. (1997). The Essentials of Logic. Research & Education Association.

Comment: Fruits:={apples, oranges, pears, peaches,...}. This does not look very promising in general.

Comment: @Conifold — Well... enumeration is a necessary step before any conceptual inference or abstraction, but you're right that it's neither sufficient nor practical in and of itself. Shoaib: can you edit in a paragraph or two from Wilson where he goes over this?

Comment: I have added a paragraph from Wilson but I am still trying to understand its use in philosophy. Is there any philosopher who used enumerative definitions of concepts to build a theoretical system? What would be the flaws in such a system? How is falsification related with enumerative definitions?

Comment: This is rather vague. It is not clear to me from this passage if a generating algorithm (like 1/n, n natural number), or even just an instruction on testing whether a given thing belongs to the extension (like "natural number without non-trivial proper divisors") counts as "enumerative definition".